# Deploying Entity Framework WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, clickonce

I've made a WPF application that uses EF6 code first database.
I've been doing it all in Visual Studio and using the default LocalDb.
The client wants to test what i've doe so far. I've tried ClickOnce application installation to my development PC. The program simply doesn't start, no window opens.... absolutely nothing happens.
I've deployed a simple WPF app and it works right away so i surmise it's the EF component.

- How do i get some sort of output log, or debugging so i can see what the error is?
- Any ideas on how to fix the error?
- Where does it get installed to?
- How can i attach the debugger?

**MY CONNECTION DETAILS from App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EEHA_Inspector.Properties.Settings.EEHA_Inspector_Model_EEHA_DbContextConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=EEHA_Inspector.Model.EEHA_DbContext;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE #2 - Windows Log Exception**

```
Application: EEHA_Inspector.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dispatch[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.__Canon, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(System.Action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

Exception Info: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass7[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.EdmMetadataRepository.QueryForModelHash(System.Func`2<System.Data.Common.DbConnection,System.Data.Entity.Internal.EdmMetadataContext>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext, System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelHashCalculator, Boolean, System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean, System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InitializeDatabase(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext+<>c__DisplayClassf`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)

Exception Info: System.Data.DataException
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].PerformAction(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(System.Action`1<System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>>)
   at EEHA_Inspector.Model.LoadObvCollection+<Equips>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at EEHA_Inspector.ViewModel.EquipRegVm+<Load>d__55.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at EEHA_Inspector.App.Main()
```

**UPDATE #2 - Windows Log Information**

```
Fault bucket 129273820369, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: EEHA_Inspector.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 58222f01
P4: System.Data
P5: 4.6.1586.0
P6: 575a1428
P7: 29fe
P8: 108
P9: System.Data.DataException
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCB7E.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_EEHA_Inspector.e_11252b12b7f6697437e3ba42fb9b6e25caa6b8_5e1d3f42_3a80d3bb

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 91f3e855-2996-40fe-b5fd-957527bbdc9d
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: f5ea3fa3886ba4e09d8362936de86fe8
```

**UPDATE #2 -Application Error in Windows Log**

```
Faulting application name: EEHA_Inspector.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58222f01
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57898e34
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000d96c2
Faulting process id: 0x5458
Faulting application start time: 0x01d239ffc4803847
Faulting application path: C:\Users\agibson\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\1RVHJ9WW.8JB\BDB4M51Q.L3R\eeha..tion_fe2d9ab6a328f11f_0001.0000_19df975805717e2b\EEHA_Inspector.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 91f3e855-2996-40fe-b5fd-957527bbdc9d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**UPDATE 3 ===================================================**

**OnModelOveride in the DbContext**

```
namespace EEHA_Inspector.Model
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Database Definition.
    /// </summary>
    public class EEHA_DbContext : DbContext
    {
...............
/// <summary>
        /// Fluent API - Entity Building Configuration. Used to define extra conditions when building the model.
        /// These are more powerful than data annotations but also more complex.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            /* FLUENT API MODEL OVERIDE - INTERMEDIARY TABLES
             *  Creates an intermediate mapping tables to hold many-to-many relationships between
             *  two tables. This is since one table can have multiple objects from another table.
             *  This intermediate table is used just as a look up table.
             *  Although its a look up table, databases must be configured to show the link two ways 
             *  since its not possible to have a many-to-many unidirectional relationship.
             *  By mapping these intermediary table; the lookup table stays clear of the relationship;
             *  while this intermediary table handles the needed mapping to make it possible.
             *  E.g. An Equip object contains a collection of Protections; while a Protection
             *  does not contain any reference to an Equip; since this is handled in a 3rd mapping table,
             *  created by these Fluent API model builder commands. */

            // Equipment Many-To-Many Look Up to ProtectionCodes
            modelBuilder.Entity<Equip>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Protections)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("EquipId");
                x.MapRightKey("ProtectionId");
                x.ToTable("EquipMapToProtections");
            });

            // InspectCheck Many-To-Many Look Up to InspectGrades
            modelBuilder.Entity<InspectCheck>()
            .HasMany(i => i.InspectGrades)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("InspectCheckId");
                x.MapRightKey("InspectGradeId");
                x.ToTable("InspectCheckMapToInspectGrades");
            });
        }


    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3.1**
Initialiser Setup

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // Set the database initializer
            Database.SetInitializer<EEHA_DbContext>(new EEHA_DbInit());
        }
}
```

SEED OVERIDE

```
#if DEBUG
#define DESTROY_DB_ONSTART //TODO remove when development progresses. Will make the database get dropped upon every start up
#endif
namespace EEHA_Inspector.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom Initialiser for the HA Database.
    /// Set the initialiliser in the App.xaml.cs class contructor (make one if not there).
    ///  <code>Database.SetInitializer<EEHA_DbContext>(new EEHA_DbInit());</code>
    /// </summary>
#if DESTROY_DB_ONSTART
    class EEHA_DbInit : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EEHA_DbContext>
#else
    class EEHA_DbInit : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EEHA_DbContext>
#endif
    {

#if DESTROY_DB_ONSTART
        /// <summary>
        /// Overide the Initialize to force a close of all connections when in testing
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Db">The DbContext to operate on.</param>
        public override void InitializeDatabase(EEHA_DbContext Db)
        {
#if DEBUG
            this.KillAllConnections(Db);
#endif
            base.InitializeDatabase(Db);
        }
#endif


        protected override void Seed(EEHA_DbContext Db)
        {
.....changes to Db
Db.SaveChanges();
base.Seed(Db);
Db.SaveChanges(); //TODO needed?
}
```

**UPDATE 4 - Using DbConfig**
Earlier today i ran the SQLExpress install manually and just went with the defaults for all options.
I've converted to DbConfig based on what i could find on the msdn update. This works again in visual studio. Making the Db at the name i gave to the DbContext Constructor.
Just to be sure i uninstalled the programs ClickOnce install. Reinstalled. When i was fiddling earlier i noticed this, but i now get a dialog box saying "Cannot Start Application || Application cannot be started. Contact the application Vendor". Unlike earlier where the app would run and then crash. This new way gives me no custom exception log, but i do get details shown below:

**Cannot Start Application Error - Details button .log**

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/TempPath/EEHA/EEHA_Inspector.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : EEHA_Inspector.application, Version=1.0.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fe2d9ab6a328f11f, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\TempPath\EEHA\EEHA_Inspector.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + External component has thrown an exception.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [9/11/2016 8:03:58 PM] : Activation of C:\TempPath\EEHA\EEHA_Inspector.application has started.
    * [9/11/2016 8:03:58 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/11/2016 8:03:58 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
        - External component has thrown an exception.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStateManager.Scavenge(UInt32 Flags, UInt32& Disposition)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SubmitStoreTransaction(StoreTransactionContext storeTxn, SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SetPendingDeployment(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionIdentity deployId, DateTime checkTime)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.SetLastCheckTimeToNow(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [9/11/2016 8:03:58 PM]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0
```

**Db Context Constructor**

```
public EEHA_DbContext() : base("TestEEHACodeDb")
    {

    }
```

**The DbConfig Class**

```
namespace EEHA_Inspector.Model
{
    public class EEHA_DbConfig : DbConfiguration
    {
        public EEHA_DbConfig()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config Removed connection string. Do i remove more?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EEHA_Inspector.Properties.Settings.EEHA_Inspector_Model_EEHA_DbContextConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=EEHA_Inspector.Model.EEHA_DbContext;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    --><!--<add name="EEHA_Inspector.Properties.Settings.EEHA_Inspector_Model_EEHA_DbContextConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EEHA_Inspector.Model.EEHA_DbContext;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />--><!--
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">-->
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**SOLUTION/ / WRAP UP**
Thanks to grek40. Particularly his exception catching code. This allowed me to start making changes to find the errors. Prior to that, the windows logs didn't help at all. 
What put me past the hurdle was using the DbContext definition he suggested. For some reason using the default DbContext constructor and a connection string seemed to make ClickOnce install expect to find an mdf file; even though attaching one wasn't specified.
The exception catch code also allowed my my debugging in release mode to find some odd exceptions (once that didn't apply to debug mode, or that made any sense to me). I've now turned off the offending code so i could proceed; the click once install now works.

Comment: Inspect the Windows' Event Logs. If there any exceptions or crashes, you can find them in the Application view.

Comment: Did you manage your references with nuget? I have an EF project that I deploy with click once and it is working for me (however, I did the setup so far ago I cant even tell what exactly I did for it). Check the required components and the application files for your click once configuration. Make sure that everything is included and required as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks dymanoid..ill try that .

Comment: Grek, do you know anyway to be sure yu have all inclusions. I did install EF with nuget

Comment: @Asvaldr its basically `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` that need to be included. Check the logs as it was suggested. Lets assume for a moment that the program is actually starting before it crashes for reasons unknown. You should implement some logging code in `App.xaml.cs` for `Startup` and `DispatcherUnhandledException`, so you can determine whats going on.

Comment: Thanks @grek40 . I'll write my own log code as you've suggested. In regards to the windows logs i found the error below.

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at ................ Blah blah too long to post

Comment: So this suggests an Database connection error to which i'm unsure of to figure out.
I searched in my user appdata and found copies of the exe buried in some obsfucated folders. It will start if i run it directly, but i have no way of knowing if thats whats running when you use the start menu to start my application.

Comment: @Asvaldr the inner exception (if any details about it are revealed) will probably be more interesting than the outer one. Also, the exception is not to long to post: just edit it into your question if it contains anything of interest. You shouldn't put relevant pieces of information into comments.

Comment: @grek40
Thanks for the advice. The full exception is now in the original question.

Comment: @Asvaldr So, `EEHA_Inspector.ViewModel.EquipRegVm.Load` and `EEHA_Inspector.Model.LoadObvCollection.Equips` would be good candidates for some exception handling, since they are in the stack trace. You need to get the exception messages for all outer and inner exceptions if you want further help on this.

Comment: @grek40 When using Visual Studio it will run. I've also found an exe buried in the appdata. \AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\1RVHJ9WW.8JB\BDB4M51Q.L3R.........
If i double click that exe it runs too.
So i have no idea what exception handling i could put in. The only thing its dependant on is the database connection.
I've also updated the source with the exceptions that happen each time

Comment: @Asvaldr : Hi, I'm also facing exact same issue you described, could you please let me know what you did to solve this. I have provided my connection string in dbcontext base constructor instead of app.config. It is working on my machine but on users machine exact same event log of yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to make sure that you actually do everything possible to catch and log the occuring exception.

Make sure to register an exception handler in `App.xaml` with `DispatcherUnhandledException`

```
<Application
    x:Class="[Your Stuff]"
    DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
</Application>
```

Implement some logging in the handler (inside `App.xaml.cs`). It should be something that summarizes the exception messages of all inner exceptions as well as their stack traces. Just write that information to some sort of log file (`C:\Temp\MyAppCrashes.log` in my example).

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    AppendExceptionMessages(sb, e.Exception);
    AppendExceptionStacktraces(sb, e.Exception);

    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\MyAppCrashes.log", sb.ToString());
}

private void AppendExceptionMessages(StringBuilder sb, Exception e)
{
    while (e != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("============== Exception ===============").AppendLine(e.Message);
        e = e.InnerException;
    }
}
private void AppendExceptionStacktraces(StringBuilder sb, Exception e)
{
    while (e != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("======== Exception Stacktrace ==========").AppendLine(e.StackTrace);
        e = e.InnerException;
    }
}
```

I hope this reveals some more information, if it's not enough, make sure to register a `Startup` handler in `App.xaml` instead of a `StartupUri`. In the startup, before creating any window, create an instance of your db context, call `db.Database.Exists()` and `db.Database.Initialize(true)`, make sure to check the `Exists` return value and wrap the calls in `try-catch`. Ofcourse, write logging details if any exception is caught.

So far for now, hope you find anything with that approach.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.
What this has shown is that for some reason, is its trying to attach an mdf file for the database. My understanding is that there isn't one.

Cannot attach the file '......\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\......_15171c3590a3cd6b\Data\EEHA_Inspector.Model.EEHA_DbContext.mdf' as database 'EEHA_Inspector.Model.EEHA_DbContext'.

Comment: @Asvaldr Actually, there is an mdf file... the only question is, where this file is kept. In case of LocalDB, it should be **local**, so you should find it somewhere. A side question that comes to mind: please edit the constructor of your db context into the question. I want to see if you use the `"Name=XYZ"` base constructor or something else.

Comment: I use the default constructor as i don't define one. But i do run an overide for OnModelCreating using the fluent API. I also overwrite the DB initialise as well. Posting all that in the OP now.

Comment: I cut and past any internal stuff out. Particulaly the Seed function. I just have functions that feed data to the database.
Whe i first put your exception code in, the exception was from the KillAllConnections. That was obviously because there was no Db to find connections for. So atm in release, this doesn't run.

Comment: @Asvaldr please see ["Database Initialization in Code-First"](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx) and change your constructor to the ConnectionString Name form. This way you at least ensure that the connection ONLY is attempted based on your configured connection string and not in any random different way.

Comment: I've changed to code context creation. It again works from VS2015 but not from the installer. It instead gives me a dialog box werror. All is explained in update 4 in OP. Btw, again words cannot express my appreciation for your help.

Comment: I think this dialog box on start has been coming up since i ran a manual installer for SQLExpress. So now the actual exe never starts

Comment: I copied the release build folder from my project directoy and copy it to another computer. That computer only has SQL LocalDbInstalled.
The WPF starts up and code functions, but no data is in the database. No exceptions are thrown. Just nothing seems to stick..... No data will display in any grids etc.
Its like its let it start up..... but can't detect that it has no connection

Comment: Is there a way i can try use another DbEngine like SQLExpress itself rather than localDb?

Comment: @Asvaldr get your connection string back into config and use the `base("Name=Your-Config-Connection-String-Name")` constructor. I don't want to fiddle with all the other strange ways of dealing with the connection. If you want a different connection string, change it in the config. `DESTROY_DB_ONSTART` looks like a valid way to get an empty database if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Particularly this exception catching code. This allowed me to start making changes to find the errors. What put me past the hurdle was using the DbContext definition you suggested. This for some reason i don't understand allowed my debugging in release mode to find some odd exceptions. I've now turned off the offending code so i could proceed; the click once install now works.