# WPF application runs in debug, crashes when deployed after a button click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-6, clickonce

I've created a WPF application in VS17. I used Entity Framework code first Version 6.0 for data. I also used some third-party libraries such as Newtonsoft.Json and EPPlus. I installed all of these through NuGet command line.

When I run the application in (with and without debugging) it works perfectly fine just as intended. I Published the application using the simple ClickOnce approach. The application publishes and I'm able to set it up. The application starts fine. Once I click a button to go to a section of the application, the application crashes.

I viewed the Windows Event viewer and know that it has something to do with deploying a database with Entity Framework. Here is the event log

```
Application: FBAContentApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.ExpandDataDirectory(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetOrGenerateDatabaseNameAndGetFileNames(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(System.Action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext, System.Func`3<System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration,System.Data.Entity.DbContext,System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase>, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InitializeDatabase(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext+<>c__DisplayClassf`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].PerformAction(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(System.Action`1<System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Include(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Include(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>>)
   at FBAContentApp.ViewModels.ProcessShipmentViewModel.PopulateAmazonWarehouse()
   at FBAContentApp.ViewModels.ProcessShipmentViewModel..ctor()
   at FBAContentApp.Views.NewShipment.PopulateGUI()
   at FBAContentApp.Views.NewShipment..ctor()
   at FBAContentApp.Views.MainMenu.NewShipment_Button_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at FBAContentApp.App.Main()
```

Furthermore, this is my App.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="FBAContentApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <userSettings>
    <FBAContentApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="CompanyAddressId" serializeAs="String">
        <value>1</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LabelPrinter" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="SaveFileDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </FBAContentApp.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is my DbContext class

```
class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AmazonWarehouse> AmazonWarehouses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CompanyAddress> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ShipmentBox> Boxes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

}
```

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461392/deploying-entity-framework-wpf-application) that sounds similar, but my application is actually starting and then crashing when moving to a section where the database is queried.

I should also mention that I used Migrations (not sure if that matters much). In the Configuration.cs, the only method I've overridden is the Seed() method to populate beginning data.

Will someone please point me in the right direction as to how to fix this?

If you need additional info please let me. I appreciate anyone's time who's willing to help.

**EDIT/UPDATE 1**
Adding the connection string didn't work, as suggested by [Dipen Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177814/dipen-shah). It caused the application to crash in debug mode. Per [sTrenat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8507673/strenat), here's the code for ProcessShipmentViewModel.PopulateAmazonWarehouse()

```
/// <summary>
/// Grabs all AmazonWarehouses from the DbContext to populate the ListBox for the NewShipment.xaml view.
/// </summary>
private void PopulateAmazonWarehouse()
{
    using (var db = new Models.AppContext())
    {
        List<AmazonWarehouse> warehousees = db.AmazonWarehouses.Include(s => s.State).ToList();

        foreach (AmazonWarehouse amz in warehousees)
        {
            AmzWarehouseModel amzModel = new AmzWarehouseModel(amz);
            AmzWarehouses.Add(amzModel); 
           //AmzWarehouses is a List<AmazonWarehouseModel>. Which is a separate model from the Entity model (AmazonWarehouse)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your connection string? I think that might be issue.

Comment: showing us `ProcessShipmentViewModel.PopulateAmazonWarehouse()` method should help us to resolve issue

Comment: some reasearches on google says you could have issue with your connection string with DataDirectory param. If so you could use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")` to get your correct Directory and then subs your old from connectionString

Answer (score 0):

Add following element in your `[app_name].exe.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FBAContentDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Database1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If you are using visual studio, you can:

1. Locate your `[app_name].exe.config` in debug folder
2. Copy connectionStrings section from debug config file and paste it to `[app_name].exe.config` file in your program's installation directory.

Also make sure, you 've **SQL Server Local DB** installed on your installation machine.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. It caused the app to crash at startup. Once I removed this, cleaned the build, and rebuilt, it worked again. :/

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your config file?

Comment: It's in the original post.

Comment: @AlfonzoAvila Check my changes, connection string I posted before was for SQL Server Db and not Local Db that is why it was crashing.

Comment: I think the reason your application is crashing because you do not have local db installed.

Comment: But it runs perfect in VS while starting with and without debugging. It only crashes when it's deployed to ClickOnce

Comment: I included SQL Server Loca lDB as part of the deployment in the Prerequisites.

Comment: Then problem is our connection string for sure, look are line: 702 in https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/DbProviderServices.cs

Comment: @AlfonzoAvila Are you dong a fresh install or updating an existing application?

Comment: Fresh install. It's a new application that's ready for deployment.

Comment: Use sql server management studio on your installation machine and connect to `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` and verify `FBAContentDB` database exists or not. If exists then kill it and try running app again.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is have a Database be created once it's deployed. Do I have to add a database in the project solution and configure the application to point to that db?

Comment: No you don't need to do that. Did you try using my updated connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. It turned out to be Visual Studio was not creating an 'x86' and 'x64' directory in the bin/Debug & bin/Release directories. Each of these should have contained SNI.dll and SNI.pdb. When I copy and pasted these directories and files into the relevant directories, I had no issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the keyboard of "F11" or log to find the error location